# Python plot a single isoline

Tags: python, matplotlib

For a function `f` an isoline at `c` is the set of points such as `f(x) = c`. Matplotlib's `contour` function plots lots of them, using different colors to separate. I want to do the much simpler task of plotting just one of them. I have achieved it in the following ugly way:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plotter(f, c, tol=0.1):
    X = np.linspace(-2, 2, 100)
    Y = np.linspace(-2, 2, 100)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    for x in X:
        for y in Y:
            if abs(f(x,y) - c) <= tol: ax.plot(x,y,marker='o',color='black')
    plt.show()

def f(x,y): return x*x + y*y
c = 1
plotter(f, c)
```

The code above plots the unit circle but in general `f` will not be that simple. It will always be a function of `2 variables` though. Since contour does much more than my plotter I assume there's a much better way to perform my task using some builtin function. Am I correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try `plt.contour(...., levels=[c])`

Comment: @JohanC I did a slight modification in x, y and use your trick to make it work. If you'd like to post an answer I will gladly accept. Otherwise, I can post my own.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plotter(f, c):
    x = np.linspace(-2, 2, 100)
    y = np.linspace(-2, 2, 100)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
    Z = f(X,Y)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    cs = ax.contour(X,Y,Z, levels=[c])
    plt.show()

def f(x,y): return x*x + y*y
c = 1
plotter(f, c)
```